# The layout design isn't showing correctly in VS 2019

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin

[(image of the design surface)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SLT5.png) I'm new to android and I was following a tutorial in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?pivots=windows). The problem is when I drag elements from toolbox to the design surface they all appear on top of each other in the visual studio BUT when I debug the program and run it on my phone It looks Just fine and exactly like the tutorial.
I have visual studio 2019 and I just downloaded everthing I needed from Sdk manager and here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter a password:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="246.5dp"
        android:layout_height="59.0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/PhoneNumberText"
        android:text="1-855-XAMARIN"
        android:layout_marginTop="29.0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Translate"
        android:layout_width="141.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/PhoneNumberText"
        android:id="@+id/TranslateButton"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="171.0dp"
        android:layout_height="33.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/TranslateButton"
        android:id="@+id/TranslatedPhoneWord"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add all your code, works well on my side. The first time I got the same with you. After I create a new layout to input by myself not copy, it works well.
[image]

It would not affect your result, maybe VS does not accept your code well for that time. Whatever, it does not matter.

It you still want to show it correctly in preview, you could try to use LinearLayout, LinearLayout would display child View elements in a linear direction, either vertically or horizontally.
LinearLayout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/linear-layout

Change: `RelativeLayout`

[image]

To: `LinearLayout`

[image]

**For this way, there is no need to use layout_below.**

Comment: thanks, changing to Linear Layout actually makes me able to place elements below each other and the preview works fine too. this was also mentioned in the documentation but I ignored it because it said "Newer releases of Visual Studio contain a slightly different app template.

Instead of activity_main.axml, the layout is in content_main.axml." and even though I do have the latest version, there is no content_main.axml in my project so I ignored the second tip: "you should change the <RelativeLayout> tag to <LinearLayout>".